# ruby on rails tutorial chapter 6 error on email validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm on chapter 6 listing 6.21 adding the REGEX for proper email validation and have double checked both user.rb and user_test.rb and can not figure out how I am getting the following error.

```
FAIL["test_should_be_valid", UserTest, 6.092359365000448]
 test_should_be_valid#UserTest (6.09s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
        test/models/user_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:UserTest>'
```

here is my user.rb

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }
end
```

and here is my user_test.rb

```rb
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example,com")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = "    "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = "   "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should not be too long" do
    @user.name = "a" * 51
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should not be too long" do
    @user.email = "a" * 244 + "@example.com"
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email validation should accept valid addresses" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@example.com USER@foo.COM A_US-ER@foo.bar.org first.last@foo.jp alice+bob@baz.cn]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
      @user.email = valid_address
      assert @user.valid?, "#{valid_address.inspect} should be valid"
    end
  end

  test "email validation should reject invalid addresses" do
    invalid_addresses = %w[user@example,com user_at_foo.org user.name@example. foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
    invalid_addresses.each do |invalid_address|
      @user.email = invalid_address
      assert_not @user.valid?, "#{invalid_address.inspect} should be invalid"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Though you did not say, it appears you are referring to [Michael Hartl's book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users).

Comment: I am indeed using Michael Hartl's book.  Next time I'm stuck I'll be sure to include references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def setup
  @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example,com")
end
```

That email is invalid. It has a comma in it.

Comment: thanks for the help, i was so worked up thinking it was the code I added i didn't think to look back at previous code.  great learning experience.